# I'm trying to make an array of char arrays using malloc and then fill in the arrays using for

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, malloc

I created pointers of arrays using malloc and is trying to fill in with strings from a text file but when I run the program I get segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  char *filename = "textfile.txt";
  int rows = 10;

  FILE *fp;
  char* line = NULL;
  size_t length = 0;
  ssize_t read;


  //make a 10 line *char array 
  char **aPointer = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*rows);
  if ((aPointer = NULL))
  {
    printf("Memory error\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  //open file
  if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file");
    exit(1);
  }

//read line from file to array
  int i = 0;
  while(((read = getline(&line, &length, fp)) != -1) && (i<rows))
  {
    strcpy(aPointer[i], line);
    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

-*Segmentation fault (core dumped)*-

how do I fill in the arrays?

Comment: I doubt those line shown is the direct cause of the crash (though they may be indirect). Please make a [short and complete program (a.k.a. a SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/) that have the problem.

Comment: Oh, and learn how to use a debugger. If you run your program in a debugger, it will stop at the location of the crash, and you can e.g. examine the function call stack and the values of variables. If nothing else, please build your program with debug information (the `-g` flag to gcc) and run in a debugger, and then post the result of the `bt` command in [the GNU debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/).

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer the question, please complete it with the code where the actual crash takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very likely cause of the error:

```
strcpy(aPointer[i], line);
```

You don't actually initialize `aPointer[i]` so the value of `aPointer[i]` is indeterminate. Using this value leads to *undefined behavior*, and as it's used as a pointer most likely a crash.

A quick solution is to set `line` to `NULL` before every call to `getline` as that function will then allocate the space needed for the line, and then you can just assign

```
line = NULL;
while(i < rows && (read = getline(&line, &length, fp)) != -1)
{
    aPointer[i++] = line;
    line = NULL;
}
```

Note: I change the order of the condition for the `while`, to use the short-circuit feature of the `&&` operator to not read a line if you read enough lines.

Don't forget to `free` the allocated memory when you're done with it.

Comment: I'm still getting the segment fault. I'm also trying to use gdb to debug but it's my first time using gdb so i'm not sure how to interpret the errors

Comment: @user238600 Build with debug information by adding the flag `-g` to your GCC command line. Then run in GDB with the commnd `gdb ./my_program`. In the GDB command prompt use the `run` command to actually run the program. When it stops due to an error, use the `bt` command to display the function call stack "Back Trace", copy the output from the `bt` command and edit your question to include it. Start with that, and we can continue to help you.

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0x00000000004007af in main () at sscce.c:44

44         aPointer[i++] = line;
(gdb) bt

#0  0x00000000004007af in main () at sscce.c:44
(gdb) bt

Comment: @user238600 At that point, do the commands `print i` and `print rows`. Those commands will show you the values of the variable `i` and `rows`. If `i` is equal or larger than `rows` you forgot to put in the check for that in the loop.

Comment: (gdb) print i
$1 = 1
(gdb) print rows
$2 = 20

Comment: @user238600 `if ((aPointer = NULL))`! The extra set of parentheses indicates you have gotten a warning about that line, one that you made go away not by checking the condition but by simply doing what it said. When you get a warning from the compiler, it's often for a very good reason, don't just disregard them!

Comment: Great! Sure I will watch out for this in the future.
Thanks a million Joachim for walking me through this!

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong your piece of code looks like:

int rows=3;

char `**aPointer = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*rows);`

aPointer[0] = "asdasdfasdfasdf";

aPointer[1] = "asdfsdf";

`aPointer[2] = "line";`

printf("\n aPointer0[%s],aPointer1[%s],aPointer1[%s]\n",aPointer[0],aPointer[1],aPointer[2]);

there is no any problem.

`Output:`

aPointer0[asdasdfasdfasdf],aPointer1[asdfsdf],aPointer1[line]

In the above example aPointer can have only reference.
If you want to copy into it you can use `strcpy()` 
e.g. strcpy(apointer[1],"myText");

Answer (score 0):

The malloc that you are calling is just allocating memory to for the pointers, and not for the strings themselves.

You can do a malloc operation for each of the strings. and then use strcpy to copy the string, it should work.

```
 aPointer[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * the_string_size_you_want);
 strcpy(apointer[0],"asdasdfasdfasdf");
```

Comment: In case the pointers are only used for read-only access, it is fine. (Though in that case aPointer should have been declared as const.)

Comment: still getting the segfault, Im trying to use gdb for the first time but im not sure how the interpret the the errors:
37     aPointer[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
(gdb) s
__GI___libc_malloc (bytes=140737488346560) at malloc.c:2845

2845 malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
2850 in malloc.c

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using trying to use an array of pointers `**apointer`, while allocating size for only the pointers for each line.

try something like this

```
int sizeOfEachRow=50;  // This should be the maximum size of any line

// Create an array of pointers. 
// Note that individual element is still an uninitialize pointer
char **aPointer = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*rows);

  --snipped--

while(((read = getline(&line, &length, fp)) != -1) && (i<rows))
  {
    // Assign memory to each pointer
    aPointer[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeOfEachRow);
    strcpy(aPointer[i], line);
    i++;
  }
```